# Looping through a page range in PyPDF PdfFileReader gives strange loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I have a [PDF](https://www.ets.org/Media/Tests/GRE/pdf/gre_research_validity_data.pdf), which consists of 4 pages and I want to separate it into separate documents and rename them based on their page number. The problem is that I have a loop to loop through each page based on: for page in range(0, pdfReader.numpages) but every time it should end it keeps going and creates duplicates. I made a print(page) to see what was going on and got:

0
1 2 3 0 0 0 0

Switching the range to range(1, pdfReader.numpages) makes the loop 1,2,3 and skips the first page. Making the loop (0, pdfReader.numpages+1) gives the correct output of files but gives the error IndexError: list index out of range

```
import os, PyPDF2, re, tika, time
from tika import parser

def split_pdf_pages(root_directory, extract_to_folder):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_directory):
        for filename in files:
            basename, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)

            if extension == ".pdf":
                fullpath = root + "\\" + basename + extension
                pdfFileObj = open(fullpath, "rb")
                pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

                for page in range(0, pdfReader.numPages):
                    print(page)
                    pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
                    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(page)

                    outputpdf = extract_to_folder + "\\" + basename + "-{}.pdf".format(page+1)
                    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)

                    with open(outputpdf, "wb") as f:

                        pdfWriter.write(f)

                pdfFileObj.close()
```

I expect to get files named filename-1, filename-2.pdf etc but instead get filename-1, filename-1-1, filename-2, filename2-2 etc UNLESS it's range(1,pdfReader.numPages) where it works correctly but skips the first page! It's driving me mad, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured it out (sorry, I'm just a hobbyist coder so it wasn't evident at first!) The program loops through every PDF in the directory (of which the extracted and renamed single page documents are contained). If you change the range to range(1, pdfReader.numPages) it was ignoring all of these newly created documents because they were all 1 page long! When it was set to 0 it included all of these newly created ones and duplicated them.

All I had to do was move the extracted and renamed folders to a different directory. Feels really obvious now that I've done it! I also removed the pdfFileObj = open(fullpath, "rb") since reader apparently does it automagically and all works now!